# Java ee batch: CWWKY0030I: An exception occurred while running the step

Tags: java, batch-processing, websphere-liberty, jsr352

I have partitioned reader and writer. There are some queries getting transaction timedout while getting resultset back from cursor. But I couldn't able to get catch the exception. I need to catch the exception and update the status back to track those reports.

Below is the exception from logs:

```
com.ibm.ws.batch.JobLogger                                     CWWKY0024W: The current chunk was rolled back to the previous checkpoint for step genGAHJSONReport in job instance 553 and job execution 553. Step metrics = [(READ_SKIP_COUNT,0), (PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT,0), (WRITE_SKIP_COUNT,0), (FILTER_COUNT,0), (COMMIT_COUNT,1), (READ_COUNT,5000), (WRITE_COUNT,5000), (ROLLBACK_COUNT,0)]

com.ibm.ws.batch.JobLogger                                     CWWKY0030I: An exception occurred while running the step genGAHJSONReport.
com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.BatchContainerRuntimeException: Failure in Read-Process-Write Loop
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeChunk(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:704)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeCoreStep(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:795)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.BaseStepControllerImpl.execute(BaseStepControllerImpl.java:295)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ExecutionTransitioner.doExecutionLoop(ExecutionTransitioner.java:118)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.executeCoreTransitionLoop(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.executeWorkUnit(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl$AbstractControllerHelper.runExecutionOnThread(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:503)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.runExecutionOnThread(WorkUnitThreadControllerImpl.java:92)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.util.BatchWorkUnit.run(BatchWorkUnit.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.context.service.serializable.ContextualRunnable.run(ContextualRunnable.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:232)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.ibm.jbatch.container.exception.TransactionManagementException: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.transaction.impl.JTAUserTransactionAdapter.commit(JTAUserTransactionAdapter.java:108)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.controller.impl.ChunkStepControllerImpl.invokeChunk(ChunkStepControllerImpl.java:656)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage3CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:978)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:778)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:711)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:165)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:113)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:162)
    at com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableUserTransactionImpl.commit(EmbeddableUserTransactionImpl.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.transaction.services.UserTransactionService.commit(UserTransactionService.java:72)
    at com.ibm.jbatch.container.transaction.impl.JTAUserTransactionAdapter.commit(JTAUserTransactionAdapter.java:101)
```

Comment: I haven't defined any checkPoint on Reader/Writer

Comment: Do you have access to the server messages.log or FFDC logs?  Can you see a WTRN0006W or other WTRNxxxx message?

Comment: You say you've observed: "queries getting transaction timedout while getting resultset back from cursor".    I wonder what indications of this you have observed ?   Maybe you could show the sample code and mention what DB / JDBC driver you're using and that might lead to a suggestion.

Comment: @ScottKurz Paritioner step, each thread runs a big complex sql and writes data as Json object. So there could be a chance the query has performance issues. Using Oracle Database and Jdbc thin driver using ojdbc8 jar

Comment: StepListener, ChunkListener, ItemReadListener all three not catching the above exception. onError  method not receiving control on this situation

Comment: OK, what about the WTRN0006W  or other WTRN message?  Do you see them in either messages.log or FFDC logs?